# Axios Interceptor Retrying with Old Token Instead of Newly Fetched Access Token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication

I have an axios instance (axiosPrivate) that I’m using for authenticated requests. When an API request returns a 401 (Unauthorized) status, I have an interceptor that triggers a refresh token mechanism. This mechanism successfully fetches a new access token, which should be used for retrying the previously failed request.

However, I’m observing an odd behavior: even after successfully fetching a new access token, the retried request still uses the old, expired token, leading to repeated 401 responses. This behavior appears like caching, but I haven’t explicitly set up any caching mechanisms with axios.

Key points:

```
1.  Initial request with axiosPrivate uses an old token and gets a 401 response.
2.  The interceptor successfully fetches a new token using the refresh mechanism.
3.  The retried request, which should use the newly fetched token, is still using the old token and hence, gets a 401 again.
```

I’ve reviewed the code but can’t pinpoint the source of this behavior. Has anyone come across a similar issue or have insights into potential solutions?

```
I changed my code, this is the new version, but it still not working:
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import useRefreshToken from './useRefreshToken';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { axiosPrivate } from '../app/axios';
import { useAuthToken } from '../app/hooks';

const useAxiosPrivate = () => {
    const refresh = useRefreshToken();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [currentAuthToken, setCurrentAuthToken] = useState<string>(
        useAuthToken.getAuthToken() ?? ''
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        const requestIntercept = axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.use(
            (config: any) => {
                const headers = {
                    ...config.headers,
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${currentAuthToken}`,
                };
                return { ...config, headers };
            },
            (error) => {
                useAuthToken.clearAuthToken();
                useAuthToken.clearRefreshToken();
                sessionStorage.clear();
                void Promise.reject(error);
            }
        );

        const responseIntercept = axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.use(
            (response) => response,
            async (error) => {
                const prevRequest = error?.config;
                if (error?.response?.status === 401 && !prevRequest?.sent) {
                    prevRequest.sent = true;

                    let newAccessToken;
                    try {
                        newAccessToken = await refresh();
                        setCurrentAuthToken(newAccessToken);
                    } catch (errorRefresh) {
                        useAuthToken.clearAuthToken();
                        useAuthToken.clearRefreshToken();
                        sessionStorage.clear();
                        navigate('/login');
                    }
                    prevRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${
                        newAccessToken as string
                    }`;

                    return await axiosPrivate(prevRequest);
                }
                return await Promise.reject(error);
            }
        );

        return () => {
            axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.eject(requestIntercept);
            axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.eject(responseIntercept);
        };
    }, [currentAuthToken, refresh]);

    return axiosPrivate;
};

export default useAxiosPrivate;
```